# Appending lists to a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `I3`. I am performing an index operation through `I4` and appending based on the length of `I3`. The current and expected outputs are presented.

```
I3 = [[(0, 0), (0, 1)], [(0, 0), (1, 0)], [(0, 1), (1, 1)], [(1, 0), (1, 1)]]

for t in range(0,len(I3)):
    I4 = [(j, -i) for i, j in I3[t]]
    I4.append(I4)
    print("I4 =",I4)
```

The current output is:

```
I4 = [(0, 0), (1, 0), [...]]
I4 = [(0, 0), (0, -1), [...]]
I4 = [(1, 0), (1, -1), [...]]
I4 = [(0, -1), (1, -1), [...]]
```

The expected output is:

```
I4 = [[(0, 0), (1, 0)],[(0, 0), (0, -1)],[(1, 0), (1, -1)],[(0, -1), (1, -1)]]
```

Comment: You're initializing I4 each time you enter the loop. Initialize it to [] before the loop and append to it within the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note `I4.append(I4)` and `I4 = [(0, 0), (1, 0), [...]]`. You're appending a list to the end of itself. That's recursive. Try to append it to an empty list.

```py
I3 = [[(0, 0), (0, 1)], [(0, 0), (1, 0)], [(0, 1), (1, 1)], [(1, 0), (1, 1)]]

temp = []
for t in range(0,len(I3)):
    I4 = [(j, -i) for i, j in I3[t]]
    temp.append(I4)
    print("I4 =",temp)
```

results in

```
I4 = [[(0, 0), (1, 0)]]
I4 = [[(0, 0), (1, 0)], [(0, 0), (0, -1)]]
I4 = [[(0, 0), (1, 0)], [(0, 0), (0, -1)], [(1, 0), (1, -1)]]
I4 = [[(0, 0), (1, 0)], [(0, 0), (0, -1)], [(1, 0), (1, -1)], [(0, -1), (1, -1)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner

```
I4 = [[(j, -i), (l, -k)] for (i, j), (k, l) in I3]
```